# Add rows in a gap dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to insert rows in my dataframe:

This is my df:

[image]

I want this result, grouped by client. I mean, I have to create this for every client present in my dataframe
[image]

Comment: How did you get the original dataframe? Was it by grouping on client and month? Or was it provided to you like that?

Comment: No, it's just provided as in the first pic.
It's already order by client and month

Comment: Also, the 'month' on the last row of picture 1 looks wrong. Is it meant to say `31/010/2018`?

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to say '31/10/2018' :)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month, format='%d/%m/%Y',dayfirst=True ,errors='coerce')
df.set_index(['month']).groupby(['client']).resample('M').asfreq().drop('client', axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

```
    client  month   col1
0   1   2017-03-31  20.0
1   1   2017-04-30  NaN
2   1   2017-05-31  90.0
3   1   2017-06-30  NaN
4   1   2017-07-31  NaN
5   1   2017-08-31  NaN
6   1   2017-09-30  NaN
7   1   2017-10-31  NaN
8   1   2017-11-30  NaN
9   1   2017-12-31  100.0
10  2   2018-09-30  NaN
11  2   2018-10-31  7.0
```

Comment: it gives me this error 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Comment: Remove duplicate row values then. I ain't able to reproduce.

Comment: @rev20  Can you mark it as an accepted answer if it helps ? :)

Comment: I have already done it, I think -.-
Do you mean the up arrow ?

Comment: Marking this as an answer by clicking on the tick.